# Python: How to call a variable in an input prompt?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to ask the following questions:

> What is the team name?
>
> How many points did (team_name) score?

I've tried the this and have gotten back an error:

```
team_name = input("What is the team name? ")

points = input("How many points did", team_name, "score? ")
```

please help!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?? Check on your environment settings. The code syntax seems to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What error are you getting?

I'm fairly confident your problem is that you are passing three parameters to input on the second line, instead of concatenating the strings which I think you're trying to do here.

Try:

```
points = input("How many points did " + str(team_name) + " score?")
```

Comment: No problem! Marking the answer as the solution is always helpful :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a python3.6 way of doing this:

```
points = input(f"How many points did {team_name} score?")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
team_name = input("What is the team name:")
points = "How many points did %s score" #%s is the variable
points_print = input(points % (team_name))
```

This is an easy way to fix your problem, use '%s' to call your variable, it will look better when printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in range(1,1000):
    for b in range(1,1000):
        for c in range(1,1000):
            if b>a and c and c>b:
                if c**2==b**2+a**2:
                    print((a,b,c))
```

**Output:**

```
(3, 4, 5)
(5, 12, 13)
(6, 8, 10)
(7, 24, 25)
(8, 15, 17)
(9, 12, 15)
(9, 40, 41)
(10, 24, 26)
(11, 60, 61)
(12, 16, 20)
(12, 35, 37)
(13, 84, 85)
(14, 48, 50)
(15, 20, 25)
(15, 36, 39)
(15, 112, 113)
... (goes on)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.